# Matrix exponential of a block diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices, block-matrices, matrix-exponential

I have an example which seems very circular.

> [image]

Doesn't this just follow from the power series definition of the exponential matrix?  I'm confused about how to actually show this as it just seems so basic.

Comment: You simply have to note that you take a power of the matrix by taking powers of the blocks, which is just matrix multiplication.

Comment: I guess that what confuses me.  The answer is in the question.  I don't understand how to prove that, it feels so circular.

Comment: Do I even need to do a proper proof?